# How to use get an array of indexes of another array elements that has common values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `arr` of objects, each object is of the form:

```
obj={id: /*some string*/,  //id is unique
     msgDetails: { content: /*some string*/,time : /*number*/ }
     }
```

In order to get an index of a specific element by its id value ,I use the following:

```
var idIndex=Babble.messages.findIndex(function(element){
   return element.id===num;
});
```

Is there a way to get all the indexes of the elements in arr that has an `id>=num` where `num` is a given number ,without for loop?

Comment: Check out [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: @MikeC  Thank you! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `for`:

```
data.filter(d => Number(d.id) > id);
```

```js
var data = [{
  id: "1",  
  msgDetails: { 
    content: "abc1",
    time: 1 
  }
},{
  id: "2",  
  msgDetails: { 
    content: "abc2",
    time: 1 
  }
},{
  id: "3",  
  msgDetails: { 
    content: "abc3",
    time: 1 
  }
},{
  id: "4",  
  msgDetails: { 
    content: "abc4",
    time: 1 
  }
}];

var filterData = function(id) { 
  return data.filter(d => Number(d.id) > id);
};

console.log(filterData(2));

// Another way

var filterId = function(cond) {
  return data.filter(d => cond(Number(d.id)));
};

console.log(filterId(id => id > 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `.map()` and `.filter()` the collection to get the indexes want.

```
var ids = Babble.messages.map((e, i) => [+e.id, i])
                         .filter(a => a[0] >= num)
                         .map(a => a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first use `map` to get the indexes and then chain `filter` to that:

```js
var Babble = {
    messages: [{ id: "1", msgDetails: { content: "abc", time: 10 }},
               { id: "3", msgDetails: { content: "word", time: 15 }},
               { id: "5", msgDetails: { content: "phrase", time: 12 }},
               { id: "7", msgDetails: { content: "test", time: 21 }}]
};
var num = 4;
var idIndexes = Babble.messages.map( (el, i) => el.id >= num ? i : null )
                               .filter(i => i !== null);

console.log('indexes with id-values greater or equal than ' + num + ':');
console.log(idIndexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will log the indexes of the items with an ID equal to or larger than the specified ID.

```js
var messages = [
  { id: 10 },
  { id: 12 },
  { id: 2  },
  { id: 20 },
  { id: 30 }
];




function getIndexesForId(id) {
  // Create a result array
  var indexes = [];
  // Loop over all messages.
  messages.forEach((item, index) => {
    // Check if message ID is equal to or larger than requested ID.
    if (item.id >= id) {
      // Push the index of the current item into the result array.
      indexes.push(index);
    }
  });
  
  // Return the array.
  return indexes;
}


console.log(getIndexesForId(10));
console.log(getIndexesForId(20));
```